# Disable named return value optimization in gcc for pure C

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization, nrvo

I failed to find a flag that controls the named return value optimization for C language. For C++ it seems to be -fno-elide-constructors.

The source code implementing it is [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-5484/gcc/tree-nrv.c) but since it is a middle-end, no front end information is spoiled even in comments.  [The manual section](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.1/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) did not exactly help either. However disassembling shows that as it is turned off on O0  and enabled on O1 it must be one of the following:

```
      -fauto-inc-dec 
      -fcprop-registers 
      -fdce 
      -fdefer-pop 
      -fdelayed-branch 
      -fdse 
      -fguess-branch-probability 
      -fif-conversion2 
      -fif-conversion 
      -finline-small-functions 
      -fipa-pure-const 
      -fipa-reference 
      -fmerge-constants
      -fsplit-wide-types 
      -ftree-builtin-call-dce 
      -ftree-ccp 
      -ftree-ch 
      -ftree-copyrename 
      -ftree-dce 
      -ftree-dominator-opts 
      -ftree-dse 
      -ftree-fre 
      -ftree-sra 
      -ftree-ter 
      -funit-at-a-time
```

C code:

```
struct p {
    long x;
    long y;
    long z;
};

__attribute__((noinline))
struct p f(void) {
    struct p copy;
    copy.x = 1; 
    copy.y = 2;
    copy.z = 3;
    return copy;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    volatile struct p inst = f();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with O0 we see that the 'copy' structure is naively allocated on stack:

```
00000000004004b6 <f>:
  4004b6:   55                      push   rbp
  4004b7:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
  4004ba:   48 89 7d d8             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x28],rdi
  4004be:   48 c7 45 e0 01 00 00    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20],0x1
  4004c5:   00 
  4004c6:   48 c7 45 e8 02 00 00    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18],0x2
  4004cd:   00 
  4004ce:   48 c7 45 f0 03 00 00    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],0x3
  4004d5:   00 
  4004d6:   48 8b 45 d8             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x28]
  4004da:   48 8b 55 e0             mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20]
  4004de:   48 89 10                mov    QWORD PTR [rax],rdx
  4004e1:   48 8b 55 e8             mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18]
  4004e5:   48 89 50 08             mov    QWORD PTR [rax+0x8],rdx
  4004e9:   48 8b 55 f0             mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10]
  4004ed:   48 89 50 10             mov    QWORD PTR [rax+0x10],rdx
  4004f1:   48 8b 45 d8             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x28]
  4004f5:   5d                      pop    rbp
  4004f6:   c3                      ret
```

Compiled with O1 it is not allocated but a pointer is passed as an implicit argument

```
00000000004004b6 <f>:
  4004b6:   48 89 f8                mov    rax,rdi
  4004b9:   48 c7 07 01 00 00 00    mov    QWORD PTR [rdi],0x1
  4004c0:   48 c7 47 08 02 00 00    mov    QWORD PTR [rdi+0x8],0x2
  4004c7:   00 
  4004c8:   48 c7 47 10 03 00 00    mov    QWORD PTR [rdi+0x10],0x3
  4004cf:   00 
  4004d0:   c3                      ret
```

Comment: Since you have identified the pass you want to disable: `-fdisable-tree-nrv`. Your "it must be one of the following" doesn't make sense.

Comment: Some of us are of course curious about **when** this is useful.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: Perhaps you should show us the source code, and difference in assembly between O0 and O1, so we know what you're trying to disable.

Comment: @user3386109 updated

Comment: @IgorZhirkov Note that in both cases (optimized or not), a pointer to the output struct is passed as an implicit argument, and the function uses the pointer to write to the final output struct. With optimization turned off, the code creates the struct on the stack (at the beginning of the function), and then uses the pointer to copy the struct (at the end of the function). With optimization turned on, the function just writes to the output struct directly. This has no effect on the observable behavior of the function.

Comment: In C++, the non-optimized code will call the *constructor* to create the temporary object on the stack, and then will call the *copy constructor* to copy the object. The C++ specification allows the optimized code to call the *constructor*, and **not** call the *copy constructor*. This will change the observable behavior of the program if the *copy constructor* has side effects. Hence, the C++ compiler gives you the option to turn that optimization off, when you want the *copy constructor* to be called.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing to that in GCC (i.e. a switch for copy elision) is `-fcprop-registers`. Copy elision doesn't exist in C, but this is the most similar feature to that. From the man page:

> After register allocation and post-register allocation instruction
>   splitting, we perform a copy-propagation pass to try to reduce
>   scheduling dependencies and occasionally eliminate the copy.
>        Enabled at levels -O, -O2, -O3, -Os.